# How to get oriented bounding boxes in three.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d, rotation, rendering, bounding-box

I use setFromObject in three.js to get bounding boxes for each object in 3d mesh. But, I get world axis aligned bounding boxes. How can I obtain oriented bounding boxes for the objects?

[image: bounding box]

Comment: Have a look at this example of OBB: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obb#webgl_math_obb

Comment: The implementation is too complicated to understand. Isn't there a way to rotate the box so that it's aligned with object?

Comment: Why can't I do something like this:
`var boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(object, 0xffff67)`
`boxHelper.geometry.rotateY(THREE.Math.degToRad(5))`

Comment: As the name implies axis aligned bounding box are axis aligned. You can't rotate them. Since the `OBB` implementation does not yet have a `setFromObject()` method, you have to define its bound manually right now.